# Why can't I construct optional<T> with an optional<S> (for S!=T)?

Tags: c++, option-type, std, c++17

If we have

```
 std::experimental::optional<int> x;
```

neither of the following lines compiles:

```
 std::experimental::optional<unsigned int> y; y = x;
 std::experimental::optional<unsigned int> z(x);
```

... even though it seems to me to make sense just like an assignment of an `int` to an `unsigned int`. Why shouldn't this work? That is, what is the pitfall that is avoided by the library not implementing the copy ctor and the assignment operator for such cases?

Comment: Is seems like currently the only elegant way how to construct an optional is through the [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/operator%3D). The reason is it's most likely the desired behaviour. The type also supports direct (but a little bit messsier) construction through [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional).

Comment: @DavidPacker: I'm not following what you're saying... the links you gave are to the currently-available assignment operators; which do not include one for other optional types. Can you explain why this is particularly related to move assignments?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the detail for the 4th move assignment operator. Seems like even that one does not allow assignment of optionals of different types. There really is no documentation out there justifying the reason, the only one who could give an answer is probably a member of the team responsible for creating the construct.

Comment: well, to be fair, it's because the C++ language is great, but its standard libraries are not. the moment I understood it my life as a C++ developer has become much simpler and better. you're complining about optional? I'd first complain about the IOStream libraries, the string library and the lack of good, out of the box, top-bottom standard libraries in the year 2016. the good thing is, is that within C++, you can write anything yourself without waiting for a new standard to be published. as a side note, you can always turn to boost-optional or facebook folly's optional instead

Comment: @DavidHaim: Well, it would be one thing if there were _no_ optional in the standard library, but since it was adopted, the question remains why wasn't conversion implemented as well? If you're arguing that, generally, choices in the standard library are often unfortunate/unreasonable/poor, can you link to somewhere making that argument more substantially?

Comment: A comparison with [`std::experimental::expected`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf) is interesting: expected is an optional with the reason nothing is there also provided.  The proposal I linked seems to be more aggressive in functionality than `std::experimental::optional`.  It also lacks a converting constructor.  I did not spot the reasoning in the paper?

Comment: since I'm talking out of my own experience and thought, I don't have any link to give. I'm sure other developers will feel the same, but won't confess how they really feel about the standard libraries. I'm taking the google approach "know the standard, but don't idolize it"

Comment: @DavidHaim: I felt I shouldn't just start adding ctors and operator='s to `std` namespace constructs without understanding why they're missing in the first place.

Comment: @einpoklum your question is legit. but my point is that I don't think the answer will be any better than "this is how it was decided", like many other problem in the standard library

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, because `std::experimental::optional` has no appropriate overload for constructor and assignment operators.

It would certainly be possible to provide such interface. In fact, boost optional, which the proposed interface is based on, does have an overloaded constructor and assignment operator for constructing from another instance of `optional`.

The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html), has a section "Comparison with Boost.Optional" which contains a comparison table which includes discussed overload. The proposal doesn't give justification for the differences except for the general statement:

> The current proposal reflects our arbitrary choice of balance between unambiguousity, genericity and flexibility of the interface.

The rationale for the descision of whether to include the overloads  is discussed in the [git repo](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/issues/16) that has the reference implementation and in [ISO C++ Standard - Future Proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-proposals/RTUK2xO0tzs/discussion) mailing list.

In the github issue, Andrzej Krzemieński, an author of the proposal, show this problematic ambiguity that the overload may cause:

> It is just not clear what should happen in the following situation:
>
> ```
> struct Tool
> {
>   Tool(int); // ctor 1
>   Tool(optional<int>); // ctor 2
> };
>
> optional<int> oi = 1;
> optional<Tool> ot = oi;
> ```
>
> Which constructor of Tool should be called and why?

Comment: How is it not clear what should happen in that context?  Ah, "do you want to construct the interior `Tool` from the `optional<int>`, or construct the `optional<Tool>` from the `optional<int>`.

Comment: @Yakk I would assume that's the essence of the ambiguity.

Comment: @Yakk: Completely agree with you. I think it's perfectly clear that when the optional<int> is engaged, it's incumbent upon the two ctors to act exactly the same, so that the ambiguity is false, Well, if only I had time to do standard lobbying...

Comment: @einpoklum The two ctors acting the same way is not the buisiness of `optional`.  The business of `optional` is which to call.  I'd argue you'd take a page from monads and make it the `int` ctor, but I could see the counter-arguement.

Comment: @Yakk: Whichever they chose to call would be ok, since it's "Tool's problem" if it's not what it expects. Whoever wrote tool is responsible to code so that it doesn't matter. I'm not familiar with monads (although I've heard the concept mentioned), but I would say having a ctor taking an optional is "as though" you had a ctor taking an int and a ctor taking a nullopt, i.e. like the pattern matching in Scala.

Comment: @einp An `optional<optional<int>>` is different than an `optional<int>`: automatic unboxing is not implied by `optional`. The `Tool` can be viewed as another wrapping around either an `int` or an `optional<int>`.  Another way to look at it: if `Tool` took a `template<class pInt>Tool(pInt)`, where `pInt` was SFINAE restricted to things that can be dereferenced to produce an `int`, and it also took an `int`, the same ambiguity would apply (without the direct questionable behavior of taking both an `optional<int>` and an `int`). Not passing `optional<int>` down makes refactoring harder as well.

Comment: @Yakk: I don't quite follow regarding the `optional<optional<int>>` - where would it come from? About the templated Tool - again, it would be up to the author of Tool to make sure that the templated ctor, when acting on an engaged `optional<int>`, would do the same thing as the ctor taking an int. It would just generalize the questionability: Taking "anything that can produce an int" means you have to obey every possible constraint/convention/norm regarding anything anyone might pass you through that ctor.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what seems to be the basic argument against converting construction (author name not clear but it's from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/RTUK2xO0tzs/discussion)):

> We have two constructors:
>
> - **unboxing**: `optional<T>` from `optional<U>`, that constructs `T` from `U` if optional is initialized
> - **forwarding**: optional from `U`, that constructs `T` from `U`.
>
> The problem is that if `T` can be constructed both from `U` and `optional<U>` we have ambiguity, now we can
>   select one of 3:
>
> 1. Compilation error and let the programmer decide
> 2. Prefer unboxing constructor
> 3. Prefer forwarding constructor

I really think that's not much of an issue at all, but I won't start this discussion here.

Comment: As a co-author of the proposal, I can confirm that this was the biggest controversy around the feature. The reason you do no have it in TS (or the Standard, at that point) is more political rather than technical. Proposals with controversial parts have the tendency to be rejected, so it seamed better not to propose it. The reasoning was, std::optional without this conversion is better than no std::optional.

Comment: @Andrzej: Do you happen to have a link to the conversion code you had _thought_ to propose, and dropped?

Comment: There wasn't any. I could not decide on the semantics (of the corner cases), so I never got to the stage where the standardese was needed. The link above (https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-proposals/RTUK2xO0tzs/discussion) contains the variants discussed and a signature for one variant. If I were to add this conversion now I would do what std::tuple does.

Comment: @Andrzej: You mean what std::tuple does w.r.t. construction with a single element of a type different that the tuple element's?

Comment: Yes. That is, (1) prefer unboxing, (2) conditionally explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the [n3672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#comparison_with_boost) proposal with [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). One of the key differences is that `std::optional` does not allow conversion from `optional<U>` to `optional<T>`. `std::optional` is modeled heavily after `Boost.Optional` (at least 1.48.0, not sure what changed since then).

A discussion on the [ISO C++ Standard - Future Proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-proposals/std$3A$3Aoptional$20optional%3CU%3E/std-proposals/uK1HfW4YTEU/4BXVkdm8MBkJ) mailing list discusses why they left out (removed) the feature. <sub>Warning: long</sub>